# how can I edit an HTML tag using PowerShell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have created PS script that queries the Event Logs on my Servers then writes the info to a plain old html file. The problem being is the html file is just that, plian. What I want to do is add jquery's DataTables to it so that I can sort and organize it.

Using the "ConvertTo-HTML -head" commandlet I can insert the code I need into the head of the document *before* the document is written. After the file is written I then need to open it and change  to .

The problem I'm having is when the script gets to the replace tag part, I get this error:

> Set-Content : The process cannot access the file C:\users\norm\Documents\eventlogs\2011\02\System\04\tc2.html' because it is being used by another process.

I suspect that it is because the pipe used to open the file still has it open. So how do I close the file? or is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks,
Norm

```
    # EventLog viewer

# Head for the HTML document. Adds the CSS and JQuery DataTables to the document. 
$h = '<head> <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />'
$h = $h + '<title>Celeste EventLog Viewer</title>'
$h = $h + '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo_table_jui.css" />'
$h = $h + '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" />'
$h = $h + '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stdcst.css" />'
$h = $h + '<script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>'
$h = $h + '<script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>'
$h = $h + '</head>'
$h = $h + '<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {$("#t1").dataTable( {"bJQueryUI": true,"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",  "bInfo" : true  } ); });</script>'
$ServerNames = "s1","s2","s3","s4","s5","s6","s7","s8","s9"
$outdir = 'C:\users\norm\Documents\eventlogs\'
$year = get-date -uformat "%Y" 
$month = get-date -uformat "%m"
$day = get-date -uformat "%d"
$count = $ServerNames.length

# Get the length of ServerNames, iterate through x until x is greater than ServerNames

for ($x=0; $x -lt $count; $x++)
    {
        # Before writing the file can begin the output directory needs to exsist. Test that it does, if not create it.
        if (( Test-Path -path $outdir$year\$month\System\$day\) -ne $True)
            {
                New-Item $outdir$year\$month\System\$day\ -type directory
            }
        if (( Test-Path -path $outdir$year\$month\Application\$day\) -ne $True)
            {
                New-Item $outdir$year\$month\Application\$day\ -type directory
            }
        echo "Getting System log from " $ServerNames[$x]
        #Query the System Event log and write it to an html file
        Get-EventLog -computername $ServerNames[$x]  -LogName System | ConvertTo-HTML -head $h | Out-File -encoding utf8 $outdir$year\$month\System\$day\"$($ServerNames[$x]).html";
        # Query the Aplication Event log and write it to an html file
        echo "Getting Application log from " $ServerNames[$x]
        Get-EventLog -computername $ServerNames[$x]  -LogName Application | ConvertTo-HTML -head $h | Out-File -encoding utf8 $outdir$year\$month\Application\$day\"$($ServerNames[$x]).html";
    }

for ($x=0; $x -lt $count; $x++)
     {
        #Open the files and replace the table tag
         Get-Content $outdir$year\$month\System\$day\"$($ServerNames[$x]).html" | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '<table>', '<table id="t1">'} | Set-Content $outdir$year\$month\"$($ServerNames[$x]).html";
     }

    #give me a message to let me know the script has completed. 
    echo "Done!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) to investigate what process accesses the file. Simiraly you can use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) (run, hit CTRL+F, type the file name, Enter).

Edit:

After looking at your code, I see the problem. 
Line `Get-Content | process something | Set-Content` is your problem. Change it to this:

```
$a = Get-Content ... | process ...
$a | Set-Content
```

Cmdlet `Get-Content` opens file, reads one line and sends the line to pipe. Then it is processed and that first line is piped to `Set-Content`. `Set-Content` would like to write, but `Get-Content` hasn't finished yet, because it read only first line.

Comment: As I suspected. I tried your suggestion and the script completes but does not make the change. I think my regex is not correct now.

Comment: Or there is no `<table>` element. You can also read all the file at once via `Get-Content -readCount 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem like it should be necessary to write it out to a file and then read it back in just to replace that tag:

```
Get-EventLog -computername $ServerNames[$x]  -LogName System |
  ConvertTo-HTML -head $h |
    foreach-object { $_ -replace '<table>', '<table id="t1">'} |
   Out-File -encoding utf8 $outdir$year\$month\System\$day\"$($ServerNames[$x]).html"
```

Comment: Someone has their "thinking hat" on today. :) Going to test this out.

Answer (score 1):

While your at it:

```
  $h = @"
  <title>Celeste EventLog Viewer</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo_table_jui.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" "href="themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stdcst.css" />
  <script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {$("#t1").dataTable( {"bJQueryUI": true,"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",  "bInfo" : true  } ); });</script>
  "@
```